# Triple boot on Dell Inspiron 15R

Tags: ubuntu, dell-inspiron

I've already installed Windows XP and Windows 7 on my Dell Inspiron 15R laptop, and I want to install Ubuntu as a third OS. Is this possible or will there be any problems?

Comment: Unlike windpwsowsows linux id very flexible . It can be installed even on pen  drives

Comment: Short answer to your first question is Yes, it is possible. If you search for "dual boot" you will find various questions and answers on here relating to dual booting between various operating systems.

Answer (score 2):

There will be no adverse consequences from installing another OS if you have enough available space for Ubuntu on your hard drive that is not already used by Windows XP and Windows 7. An Ubuntu installation requires a bare minimum of 5GB space on the hard drive. Since you will probably be installing some apps in Ubuntu, you should plan on giving Ubuntu more disk space than that, depending on your requirements. My recommendation is to give Ubuntu *at least* 10GB disk space. Installing Ubuntu will replace the Windows bootloader with its own GRUB bootloader which will allow you to choose to boot to either Windows XP, Windows 7 or Ubuntu when you start the computer.

In the Ubuntu installer in the **Installation type** screen, select the first option *Install Ubuntu alongside them*.

[image]